# How to catch location/destination path

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I'm building an app on OSX using C++/Qt. The app is managing to transfer file from the app to the finder. I use the Drag and Drop.

The app is displaying files from an android device. I can copy file from Finder to the android device without any issue.

but I can not make it work from android device to finder. I have the DragLeaveEvent which is triggered but I still don't understand how to catch the data for the destination.

When leaving the app, the mouse is on the desktop I should be able to git the path of where is the cursor to start a copy with the source (I already get it) and destination.

When dragging from Finder to the app, I get the source using the mimeData.urls and I was expected to use the same when dragging from the app to the finder but it's not supported or urls is empty

```
void TreeView::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << "On Drag Leave Event";

    QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> item;
    item = this->selectedItems();
    if (item.empty())
        return;
    else {
        QStringList ListOfFiles;
        QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
        const QMimeData *mimeData = clipboard->mimeData();

        QStringList pathList;
        QList<QUrl> urlList = mimeData->urls();

        for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size() && i < 32; ++i)
        {
            pathList.append(urlList.at(i).toLocalFile());
            qDebug() << urlList.at(i).toLocalFile();

        }

        for (int i=0; i<item.count();i++) {
            ListOfFiles.append(item[i]->text(0));
            qDebug() << item[i]->text(0);
        }
    }
    event->accept();
    QTreeWidget::dragLeaveEvent(event);

}
```

Any idea ?
Thanks